# Firefox gestures in 22.04 don't work

Tags: firefox, gestures

How can I get firefox to use pinch to zoom in/out on my laptop using wayland and ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (at least in terms of touch screen scrolling) is to open the file "/usr/bin/firefox" and replace `exec /snap/bin/firefox "$@"` with `exec env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /snap/bin/firefox "$@"`. Maybe that also works for you?